# Can I use jMonkeyEngine for Android Devices?

Tags: android, jmonkeyengine

I am trying to make a simple 3D game for Android, and I want to use jMonkeyEngine. Can I do this? How? Can someone show me an example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to their [blog](http://jmonkeyengine.com/blog/blog/2010/02/10/android-support-confirmed-for-jme3/) Android support is coming with the upcoming jMonkeyEngine3, so it looks like you will have to wait for their next official release.

Answer (score 1):

Though it's a old question to answer but I think many of us still looking for the solution.

jMonkeyEngine for Android:

> The answer is Yes! You can use jMonkeyEngine3 (JME3) to develop 3D game for Android.

How to start:

> Android integration and deployment in JME3 is nicely described [here](http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3%3aandroid)!

Example

> You can find some good beginner JME tutorial [here](http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3#tutorials_for_beginners) with sample/example code. You can use these examples for Android.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this until discovering this video with no audio... 
[Running jME3 on Android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=np3N4pCCTPo)

1) Right Click your project and Select "Properties" from the menu:
[image: Project Properties]

2) Check the "Enable Android Development" check-box

3) Select the appropirate "Android Target"

4) Select Android as your target from the drop down:
[image: Android Target]